# How do you fix malformed filter error while using ldpa3

Tags: python

So I am working with ldpa3, and with it, I was reading from a .json that in one part had a string that had `(` and `)` in it.

Apparently using those characters returns the error `malformed filter` if used.

To fix this problem, I replaced both `(` and `)` in my string with wildcards and I got the program to work perfectly.

I was wondering why ldpa3 keeps throwing malformed filter error and how to fix this error without throwing wildcards?

Comment: using this link, I figured out all the characters I have to replace
https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/searches.html?highlight=filter#the-ldap-filter

Comment: The solution I found was I used `string.replace()` as the string was passing through the `try` so I only modified the local string in that class def versus changing the .json or main